# How to use a UIContainerView in IB with XIBs?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In Xcode 6 i am trying to add a container view inside a view controller hosted inside a navigation controller. However in the Objects library there is no container view option. I am not using a storyboard just a normal xib. Are container views only relevant to storyboards. Do I just use a normal `UIView` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIContainerView` embeds a child view controller. Interface Builder expects to display the child view controller the container view embeds -- which works fine in storyboards, but isn't possible using XIBs since they can only display a single view controller.

If you absolutely cannot use storyboards in your project (you really should, they are great!), your best option is to use a `UIView` as a placeholder and add the child view controller via code.

Here's a handy category I use on `UIViewController` to handle all the details of adding a child view controller to a placeholder view.

```
- (void)addContentController:(UIViewController*)viewController inView:(UIView *)inView
{
    viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];
    [inView addSubview:viewController.view];
    NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"presentedView" : viewController.view};
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[presentedView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];
    [inView addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[presentedView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict];
    [inView addConstraints:constraints];
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was going to use a segment control to swap the viewcontrollers. I take it that self.view is the parameter to pass to inView:

Comment: @tech74 `inView` should be whatever view you want to embed your child view controller's view in. Typically I create a placeholder view in IB for this. That way you can manage your constraints on that view from within IB. The helper method assumes you will want the child view's frame to hug the placeholder's frame.

Answer (score 0):

A container view is used to embed another view controller.

Xibs are used for a **single** view / view controller, thus you won't have another view controller to embed.

And you can use a placeholder view in the Xib and programmatically add embed the second view controller with `addChildViewController:` and add it's view with `addSubview:`.